# qrcode-0.1 with Grails 2.0.1

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Look this is my problem: I have updated to Grails 2.0.1 and now I have to make a QR Code. I have installed the qrcode plugin 0.1 but it is not working. I'm usign the tag:

```
<qrcode:image text="${createPromoInstance.id}" />
```

but it seems it doesn't do anything. I debugged with google chrome and I realized that in the "Elements" tab, the tag is being changed for `<call></call>`
I was asking yesterday about this, and someone said me that the plugin has some bugs that doesn't work with Grails 2.0.1, and he gave me some advices about what can I do.
For example, I editted the QRController like this:

```
class QrcodeController{
   QRCodeRenderer qrcodeRenderer = new QRCodeRenderer()

   def index = {
       qrcodeRenderer.renderPng(response, request.getHeader("REFERER"), 300i)
   } //It doesn't have any change

   def url = {
      String uri = params.u
      String size = getSize(params)
      qrcodeRenderer.renderPng(response, uri, size.toInteger().intValue())
   } //it doesn't have any change

   protected String getSize(Map params){
      String size = params.s
      if(!size || size.matches(/\D\)) {size = "128"}
      return size
   } //I have added the "protected word"

   def text = {
      String content = params.t //it used to be params.text
      String size = getSize(params)
      qrcodeRenderer.renderPng(response, content, size.toInteger().intValue())
   }
}
```

and he said if I make those changes it will work, but no, it doesn't! I'm trying to render the code in an empty gsp just to try it out like so:

```
<%page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title><title>
<head>
<body>
   <div>
      <qrcode:image text="${createPromoInstance.id} />
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As I understand it should work, but it doesn't. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? I have to do something else to get the rendered QR Code?
Thanks for the help! 
Jonatan!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer... I will just leave it here if anyone need it.
to get this working you need to do some changes as I wrote before.

```
protected String getSize(Map params{ //it used to be String getSize(Map params)
   String size = params.s
   if (!size || size.matches(\/D/) {size = "128"}
   return size
}
```

and

```
def text = {
  String content = params.t //it used to be params.text
  String size = getSize(params)
  qrcodeRenderer.renderPng(response, content, size.toInteger().intValue())
}
```

but this is not everything, you have to change something else in the BuildConfig like so:

```
//find the plugin call
plugins{
   //this is how my plugins call looks like, here you might see the calls of the plugins you have installed
   runtime: ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
   runtime: ":jquery:1.7.1"
   runtime: ":resources:1.1.6"
   //and you gotta add this
   compile: ":qrcode:0.1"
   /*.
   .
   .*/
   build: ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
 }
```

Then you must go to the plugin taglib "QRCodeTagLib" and replace this:

```
def image = {attrs->
  def size = attrs.height?:attrs.width
  String text = attrs.text
  String src = createLink(controller:'qrcode',action:'text',params:[t:text,s:size])
  //it used to be like this
  /*def mkp = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(out)
       mkp{
          img(alt:url, src:src)
       }
  */
  //and now it looks like this
  out <<"<img alt=\"${text}\" src=\"${src}\"/>"
}
```

and that's it, your QR Code will be rendered!

Hope it will be useful for anyone!
Jonatan!!
PD: The credit is not mine for this code, somebody helped me on the grails facebook page! Lots of thanks for Ingo. :)
ah! Other thing... He added something in the bootstrap but it didn't work for me, in the bootstrap he put:

```
QRCode m = new QRCode()
m.save()
```

try it and let me know if that works for you! :)